# Recursion in getServletContext() in GenericServlet

Tags: java, servlets

Below are the 2 methods from the ***GenericServlet*** class,

```
    public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
        return this.config;
    }

    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return getServletConfig().getServletContext();  // is this RECURSION?
    }
```

Secondly, What will this method ***getServletContext()*** finally returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not recursion because the `getServletContext()` call within the method is called on the `SevletConfig` object and **not** on the servlet itself.

The reason it may seem like recursion is that `GenricServlet` ***implements*** `ServletConfig` and exposes all the methods of that *interface* on itself but it does so by delegating all these calls to a `ServletConfig` object held by its instance member variable `config`.

This is done so for a convenient usage of servlet's own `ServletConfig` within its `doGet()`, `doPosts()` methods. For example, say, the servlet wants to read its initialization parameters defined in the *web.xml*, within the `<servlet>` tags with `<init-param>`s.

Then instead of doing this

```
out.write(getServletConfig().getInitParameter("adminEmail"));
```

the servlet can directly invoke this

```
out.write(getInitParameter("adminEmail"));
```

The same shorthand works for `getServletContext()` as well. If the `GenericServlet` class didn't implement `ServletConfig` you would've had to call `getServletConfig().getServletContext()` everywhere.

---

> But GenericServlet implements ServletConfig. Hence again, the call will be on GenericServlet's method

No, this is recursion

```
public String toString() {
    return toString(); // BAD! StackOverflowError
}
```

and this is not

```
public String toString() {
    return instanceVar.toString(); // OK
}
```

Just because the method names are same, doesn't make it *recursion*.

You have to see on **which** object the method is being called. In the servlets' case, first call is on the `GenericServlet` object (or technically a subclass of it) and the second call is on its `config` member variable -- a `ServletConfig` object.

Comment: But GenericServlet implements ServletConfig. Hence again, the call will be on GenericServlet's method

Comment: What do you mean by, ' But, that's done for convenient usage within doGet(), doPosts() methods' ?

Comment: I voted up but still didn't get it. How will i reach to this method getServletContext() inside the getServletContext() method?

Comment: Okay, answer this: What happens in my second toString() example?

Comment: instanceVar.toString()- Here you are invoking the method toString of the STRING class on instanceVar to get a string representation

Comment: Correct!! Similarly, when getServletContext() is called it calls getServletConfig().getServletContext(). Now, you know from the code you posted that getServletConfig() returns this.config i.e. an instance variable. So, the previous call becomes this.config.getServletContext() i.e. the inner call is fired on the ServletConfig instance object, not the outer/enclosing GenericServlet object. Any doubts?

Comment: this is ofcourse i know very well. But where is the second method i.e this.config.getServletContext() defined. I know ServletConfig provides it, but where is the implementation

Comment: Whenever a Servlet is pressed into service for the first time, the web container creates a ServletConfig object and passes the same as part of the servlet's initialization to the GenericServlet#init(ServletConfig) method. This method saves the config object as a member variable (this.config). This config object's implementation is container specific i.e. it will differ from Tomcat to OC4J to JBoss etc. You'll have to see Apache Tomcat's source code to see the actual class implementation.

Comment: You said, This method saves the config object as a member variable (this.config). But config is declared as transient in GenericServlet

Comment: Save as in store a reference to an object in a variable. How come you confuse it with transient? That's serialization, a totally different topic.

Comment: One more thing. When you said, 'You'll have to see Apache Tomcat's source code to see the actual class implementation.', you mean the implementation of ServletConfig interface.

Comment: Correct! In your servlet print config.getClass(). This will give you the inetrnal class name. Then check it's implemenation after downloading the source from [here](http://apache.bytenet.in/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.18/src/apache-tomcat-8.0.18-src.zip).

Comment: I am going to check it. That means that this implementation is other than GenericServlet.

Comment: Yes, but their implementation could extend from GenericServlet. But the bottom line is that it will be a different object, hence no recursion.

Comment: it's org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperFacade containing getServletContext method. But how does this config reference in GenericServlet knows which one getServletContext method to call. GenericServlet or StandardWrapperFacade mentioned above.

Comment: Due to polymorphism, the method that would finally run at runtime will depend on the actual type of the config object which as you've found is StandardWrapperFacade. The instance of this object will be made available to the servlet by the web container by calling GenericServlet.init(ServletConfig) but passing it StandardWrapperFacade which works because StandardWrapperFacade implements ServletConfig.

Comment: Actually, the way all this works uses almost all the important principles of Object-oriented programming. So, you may need to brush up on OOPs again esp. how a parent class or interface type reference can point to a subclass or implementing object instance.

Comment: Thank you very much Ravi. Indeed you helped me a lot in understanding the internals regarding Servlets. I know the call will be resolve at the runtime the very momemt you talked of the other implementation besides GenericServlet. The problem actually arises because almost every tutorial on the web mentions that the Servlet Engine passes/constructs(parsing the xml) a config obj to init of GenericServlet. They must have mention it in context to the implementation provided. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, that's true but the tutorials don't touch on that much because how the containers implement these interfaces internally is not part of the JEE spec. Plus, the implementation differs from container to container as well.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you with your doubts. Keep digging, that's how one learns.